# Using ssh handler links to paste into existing iterm tab

Tags: macos, ssh, applescript, osx-snow-leopard, iterm

I use an ssh gateway, which uses key-auth. This means my work station is not keyed into any of the servers I work with daily. I use ssh:// handlers, which I had a script for on my PC to work with putty (click link, then click open putty window to paste). I wanted to do something similar with applescript, but have been unable to even get rudimentary scripts to work.

Is there an easier way? I really just need to be able to convert "ssh://root@ip:port" to "ssh root@ip -p port" (ex.) and paste it into the active iterm2 tab. If there is a more elegant way to do this I am open to suggestions. I have found dozens of pages that skip around this idea, but I really can't wrap my head around the applescript they use (nor can I seem to reproduce it).

edit for clarification:

I always have an ssh session to the gateway open in iterm, which is where i keep multiple screens of various things I am doing. Ideally I just want to throw this into my clipboard so I can just tab to my gateway and cmd+v. This is easier than interacting with iterm, however I can't wrap my head around the applescript for parsing the argument line. Additionally I have modified info.plist to accept "ssh" as the scheme, but would something else be needed?

=---------------------=

This is as far as I have gotten after continuing my search, and while it mostly works in CLI during testing (open script.app/ ssh://root@127.0.0.1:22), It does not work with my browser. Frankly, I don't really know what I am doing.

```
on open location this_URL

    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"ssh://", ":"}
    set preBuff to item 2 of the text items of this_URL
    set prePort to item 3 of the text items of this_URL as integer
    set preLine to "ssh " & prebuf & " -p " & prePort


    set the clipboard to preLine


end open location
```

=---------------------=

I have worked on this a bit more, and:

```
on open location this_URL

    set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"ssh://", ":"}
    set preBuff to item 2 of the text items of this_URL
    set prePort to item 3 of the text items of this_URL as integer
    set preLine to "ssh " & preBuf & " -p " & prePort

    -- debug dialog
    display dialog the [preLine]
    buttons("exit")

    set the clipboard to preLine


end open location
-- debug dialog
display dialog the ["didn't run"]
buttons("exit")
```

The "didn't run" dialog will pop up when a ssh:// link is clicked in the browser, however everything enclosed in "on open location" doesn't appear to be touched.

EDIT: My info.plist -
http://pastebin.com/JgRps1B5

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Wouldn't this be easily done with a shell script on your desktop with `iterm ssh -p port root@host` (not sure about iterm's precise command line syntax)? Or maybe just a set of scripts on the gateway box?

Comment: This would normally apply, however every box can only be keyed by the master key from the gateway. I deal with thousands of servers, and they are all keyed to the gateway (sorry if the wording here gets redundant). On our windows boxes we have a program in place that does the ssh handling, however few of us run OSX so there was nothing put in place. 
Simply, I am trying to copy ssh:// links into the clipboard to be pasted into the gateway.

Also, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually gotten this to work now, using this:

```
on open location test
    if test contains "rm" then --shitty sanitization
        display dialog the ["Link may be malicious"] --debug
    else
        set oldDelims to AppleScript's text item delimiters
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"ssh://", ":", "/"}
        set preHost to item 2 of the text items of test
        set prePort to item 3 of the text items of test as integer
        set final to "ssh " & preHost & " -p " & prePort
        set the clipboard to final
        display dialog the [final] --debug
    end if
end open location
```

I don't know why one worked and the other didn't, I can only guess there was some error it was not passing. The end result:

ssh://root@127.0.0.1:22/ (ex) gets placed in the clipboard as "ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 22"

So for the most part, this is solved (I just don't know why).